# Trying to click a button but keep getting an error with xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to automate pulling credit charges into an excel sheet; I have managed to get the login working. Once I enter the website, there's a button titled "Search". I cant seem to figure out how to have that button clicked.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import time

chromedriver = "C:/Python_Ex/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
delay = 30
driver.get("https://global.americanexpress.com/activity/date-range?from=2020-05-01&to=2020-05-30")

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="eliloUserID"]').send_keys("removed")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="eliloPassword"]').send_keys("removed")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginSubmit"]').click()

time.sleep(10)

#print(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/section/div[4]/div[2]/button'))
search_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/section/div[4]/div[2]/button')
search_button.click()
```

html tag is as follows

```
<button class="btn btn-fluid" tabindex="0" type="button"> <span>Search</span></button>
```

Xpath as follows

```
//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/section/div[4]/div[2]/button
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `click()` on the `<button>` with text as **Search** using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-fluid[type='button']>span"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-fluid']/span[text()='Search']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for all the help What does './span[text()='Search'' do to the Xpath? I tried it with just the class before but it didn't work. I guess the span[...] was the missing component; curious how it gets it work?

Comment: @newbie_khan `//span[text()='Search']` looks for the text _Search_ within a `<span>` element within a parent `<button>` element. Glad to be able to help you.

Comment: QQ: How would i access May 27 text in the html code below?
<div class="position-relative"><div id="transaction_320201490781444914" class="flex flex-wrap flex-column-md flex-align-center border-b pad-1-tb-sm-down " style="text-decoration: none; min-height: 50px;"><div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 pad-responsive-l dls-accent-gray-05"><div class="checkbox "><input id="320201490781444914" class="form-control" type="checkbox"><label for="320201490781444914"><span>May 27</span>

Comment: Also, once all the search button is clicked will I be able to access the new contents on the webpage using driver or do I have to do something to load the new contents in driver?

Answer (score 0):

After login submited, try to add the below code:

```
...
...
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginSubmit"]').click()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-fluid']//span[text()='Search']"))).click()
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```